# The query time difference between EXPLAIN ANALYZE and AWS slow query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

I would like to measure the query execution time.
My database is Amazon Aurora MySQL3 (with MySQL 8.0 compatibility).

I tried two ways of measuring:

1. EXPLAIN ANALYZE
2. see slow query log in cloudwatch.

However, I found that 1 and 2 returned different results for the same SQL statement.

the result from 1:

```
# Query_time: 7.719750  Lock_time: 0.000121 Rows_sent: XXX  Rows_examined: XXX
```

the result from 2:

```
-> Filter: (XXX like XXX)  (cost=6258.00 rows=XXX) (actual time=0.046..132.199 rows=XXX loops=1)
    -> Table scan on XXXX  (cost=6258.00 rows=XXX) (actual time=0.036..71.230 rows=XXX loops=1)
```

From my understanding...
1 says that my query takes about 7.7 seconds to execute.
2 says that my query takes about 0.132 seconds to execute.

My Questions are:
・Is my understanding of query execution time correct?
・Why are their execution times different?
・Which is more reliable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have those in the right order?  Did you run each twice (to avoid caching issues)?

Comment: @RickJames
Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did it several times in random order.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804082/does-rows-sent-affect-query-time
As mentioned above, does Rows_sent might affect Query_time?

If so, should I think the following way?
[ time for Rows_examined: 0.132seconds ]
[ time for sending found rows: (7.7 - 0.132)seconds]