# Does Rows_sent affect Query_time?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I executed the LIKE clause SQL twice as below.
My table has 50000 rows and the first SQL returns 50000 rows.
On the other hand, the second SQL returns 0 rows.

I thought that in both cases MySQL had to examine all 50000 rows to execute.
but Why is Query_time of the second SQL much faster than the first one?

Am I missing something?
Does Rows_sent influence Query_time?
If so, how does it affect?

```
# Query_time: 4.575865  Lock_time: 0.000120 Rows_sent: 50000  Rows_examined: 50000
SELECT * FROM `XXXX` WHERE `XXXX` LIKE "%Tom%";


# Query_time: 0.163456  Lock_time: 0.000128 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 50000
SELECT * FROM `XXXX` WHERE `XXXX` LIKE "%TTTTTTTTOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMM%";
```

I'm using Amazon Aurora MySQL3 (with MySQL 8.0 compatibility).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some effort [that is, time] to package up the rows and send them to you.

Comment: Thanks! so, is the time spent sending rows included in Query_time?

Comment: Yes.  Note, also, that it is "elapsed" time, not "CPU" time.